# Oracle BI Publisher Report output is not opening in LibreOffice

Tags: oracle, oraclereports, bi-publisher, oracle-apps

We are using Oracle BI Publisher as repoting tool.
We have designed the template in RTF format and uploaded into bi publisher also using the query to generate report output as Excel format.
But the excel output is not opening in LibreOffice 4.3.
How to open the excel output in LibreOffice 4.3.
any idea's please...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

BI Publisher is not certified to export to LibreOffice.
That being said what is happening when you publish the report? Is it opening at all in any program?